# what the alternative of FETCH_KEY_PAIR if it is deprecated in Doctrine DBAL 3.0

Tags: fetch, deprecated, dbal

It was very convenient tool to fetch data from SELECT as $id => $value in result:

```
$result = $this->conn->executeQuery("SELECT id, value, FROM table")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

, but now I have an ERROR:

> Using a PDO fetch mode or their combination (12 given) is deprecated
>   and will cause an error in Doctrine DBAL 3.0
>   Can you suggest good alternative of this data scheme?

Comment: There's a DBAL feature request for adding a corresponding fetch mode method, see https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/4289